# Why I am losing this.variable value on angular?

Tags: angular

I call a function that instanciate my controller variable value, but when I do a for each on this variable, angular say me that it's undefinded. Where do i need to instanciate this variable ?

My variable is first instanciated in the constructor, and when I call it in my html file, it work well, but when I call it in the ngAfterViewInit, it's undefined.

```
//This is where I call my function and where I use my variable
ngAfterViewInit(){
this.getFamilles();
 if(this.listeFamilles) {
   for (let f of this.listeFamilles._embedded.familles) {
     this.draw("#" + f.nom, this.arriel1, {dateDimension: false, color: 
 f.color, labelFormat: "%Y"})
   }
 }else{
   console.log('bug');
 }
}


//This is my function that instanciate the variable
getFamilles(){
this.serviceFam.getAllFamilles()
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.listeFamilles = data;
  }, err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

I expect the variable not to be undefined

Comment: `if(this.listeFamilles)` - If this check passes, `listeFamilles` cannot be undefined. I'd rather think that either  `listeFamilles._embedded` or  `listeFamilles._embedded.familles` is undefined. Did you try debugging your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
getFamilles(){
  this.serviceFam.getAllFamilles().subscribe(data => {
    this.listeFamilles = data;

    if(this.listeFamilles) {
      for (let f of this.listeFamilles._embedded.familles) {
        this.draw("#" + f.nom, this.arriel1, {dateDimension: false, color: 
        f.color, labelFormat: "%Y"})
      }
    } else {
      console.log('bug');
    }
  }, err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

Comment: @porgo Though, this snippet works the OP has no idea why. I suggest you'd add an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Because the getAllFamilies method is an Observable which is asynchronous. You will not be sure when the subscribe is triggered. It can be anytime. Right now you are experiencing it is completed after your logs.

Comment: *but when I do a for each on this variable, angular say me that it's undefinded* - This means that the `if(this.listeFamilles)` check passed (= `this.listeFamilles` is not `undefined`), so even if what you say is completely correct the problem is not the observable here.

Comment: OK @Robin, thank you for you answer. So where do i call  to call it before?

Comment: you can handle the data in subscribe, just like @porgo suggested or you can use `Router` and it's `resolvers` to resolve data before navigating to your component.

Comment: @Ludevik , ok but how do you use resolvers ? I'm sorry i'm not used to Angular, so I have difficulties.

Comment: @MaximeAlza check the documentation on resolve: https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve and on router: https://angular.io/guide/router